# Change Smarty delimiter tags for just css file?

Tags: php, css, smarty

I want to use Smarty to render my CSS file, mainly so I can use a variable for the location of images.  In order to avoid errors I need to either user {literal} tags around everything or else change the delimiter so { and } are not Smarty tags.

My question, is it possible to only have that one file use something different for the Smarty tags? If so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer to your question, but one popular method of doing this is having style sheets and images in neighbouring directories, and referencing them using relative `../images` references.

If that is not an option - I don't think you can control delimiters on a per-file basis in Smarty. You can however [change the delimiter before the template is parsed](http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=SmartyFrequentlyAskedQuestions#template-2):

```
$t = new Smarty;
$t->left_delimiter = '<!--{';
$t->right_delimiter = '}-->';
```